# Django Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK when checking perms

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error `Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK` whenever I try to check for permissions in the template whose corresponding view has a `@transaction.commit_manually` decorator.

template:

```
<!-- html stuff -->
{% if perms.myApp.add_table1 %}
    {# show html elements #}
{% endif %}
```

Once I remove the permissions condition, no errors are present. Non permissions related `if` conditions are okay, e.g. `{% if user.is_superuser %}{% endif %}`

**UPDATE**: even if the the permissions checking is not on the template that the view renders, but was extended from, it still has this error.

e.g. permission checking in nav_bar.html, and view renders expense.html which extends nav_bar.html would cause the same error.

view.py:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def add_expense(request):
    # do stuff here
```

i've tried removing the decorator and there is no exceptions of any kind, everything works. But when I put the decorator on, error occurs

urls.py:

```
# other stuff omitted
(r'^myApp/expenses/add/$', add_expense),
```

**UPDATE #2:**

When the user is a superuser, there's no problem as well. I believe that is because it doesn't bother checking the permissions since the user is a superuser

Also I've included code

```
@login_required()
@transaction.commit_manually
def add_expense(request):

    request.session.set_expiry(1800)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_input = AddExpense(request.POST)

        if form_input.is_valid():
            try:
            # after validation data is cleaned
                cd = form_input.cleaned_data
                # cleaned data is a dictionary
                input_date = date.today()
                user = request.user.username


                new_record = table1.objects.create(
                    amount = cd['amount'],
                    date = cd['date_of_expense'],
                    username = user
                    )
                new_record.save()
                transaction.commit()
                return render_to_response('forms/add_expense_success.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            except Exception, e:
                pass
                transaction.rollback()
                return HttpResponse(None)
        else:

            return render_to_response('forms/add_expense.html', {'form': form_input},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        # loading this gives error, not sure the top part
        form = AddExpense()
        return render_to_response('forms/add_expense.html', {'form': form, 'page_title': '新增支出'},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Not an answer per se, but just double checking: Do you have a transaction.commit() at the end of your "#do stuff here" code block?

Comment: it's under a condition, so no, not necessarily. But I don't believe this has an effect. Adding `transaction.commit()`/`transaction.rollback()` to every condition results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm what the error message implies, you're on Postgres, right?

If so, one suggestion: in your `# do stuff here` block, above, I'll bet that you're not manually committing after reads even if you are after writes.

As of Django 1.3, transaction-managed reads are counted as dirty - not just writes - so you'll need to `commit()` after those, too.

See the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#transaction-management) for more detail.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I've tried that already, same error. Adding transaction.commit() to every condition. And if you read my question, I am only getting the problem when I check permissions in the template, if I don't use the check permissions it I get no error. So I believe the problem lies somewhere there.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a bug in your permissions-checking there, then. Might that be leaving dirty reads uncommitted?

Answer (score 0):

It cause by  context_instance=RequestContext(request),

see the solution down here by @Marcin

[Django Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955321/django-transaction-managed-block-ended-with-pending-commit-rollback)

Answer (score 0):

i get this error message while trying to reduce permissions for the accessing user.

- postgresql 9.1`
- python 2.7.3
- django 1.3.1

if running as superuser (admin role) no problem at all, if running as user (user role) the error comes up.
the user has all (even grant) rights on all django related tables and even on the database and schema too but it still gives the error.

what could cause this? so far i could debug this, its just superuser rights missing, else superuser and user have same rights.

code:

```
@login_required
@transaction.commit_manually
def sipuser_add(request, extension_id):
    member = members.objects.get(nickname=request.user.username)
    extension = extensions.objects.get(id=extension_id)
    nickname = request.user.username
    if extension.id_members.nickname == member.nickname:
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        secret = pwgen()
        cursor.execute("SELECT func_create_sipuser('%s','%s',%s)" % (nickname, secret, extension_id) )
        ret = cursor.fetchone()
        logger.debug("created extension_id: %s - stored procedure 'func_create_sipuser' returned: %s" % (extension_id, ret) )
        pin = 1234
        timeout = 15
        cursor.execute("SELECT func_create_voicemail_from_phonenumberid(%s,'%s',%s)" % (extension_id, pin, timeout) )
        ret = cursor.fetchone()
        logger.debug("created voicemail for extension_id %s - stored procedure 'func_create_voicemail' returned: %s" % (extension_id, ret) )
        cursor.close() # is this needed and/or on the right position called?
        connection.commit()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/extensions/')
```