# Django Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-orm

I have a view function which needs to be manually transaction managed, but when I apply the `@transaction.commit_manually` decorator, django ALWAYS raises the below exception.

As you can see from the code trace below, the transaction is committed right before return from the view.

I am using sqlite, both on windows and linux, with django 1.4.

The following is the output of django_trace, followed by the exception. To be clear: this happens whether or not I use django_trace, and when there are no decorators, no exception whatsoever is raised. This is not being caused by a "swallowed" exception.

Note that line 60 in the below is inside a context processor, and hence outside of the `commit_manually`-wrapped view.

```
01->mainapp.views:1321:         transaction.commit()
01->mainapp.views:1322:         return render_to_response('mainapp/templates/incorporate.html',
01->mainapp.views:1323:                                       RequestContext(request, form_params))
02-->mainapp.views:60:     transaction.rollback_unless_managed()
02-->mainapp.views:61:     return {'home_login_form': AuthenticationForm(request)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\oneclickcos\mainapp\decorators.py", line 26, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 209, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 203, in __exit__
    self.exiting(exc_value, self.using)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 288, in exiting
    leave_transaction_management(using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 52, in leave_transaction_management
    connection.leave_transaction_management()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 119, in leave_transaction_management
    raise TransactionManagementError("Transaction managed block ended with "
TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

To be clear, I have checked the other questions on this topic, and they DO NOT have the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that during template rendering, there was database access, so the usual pattern like:

```
return render_to_response('mainapp/templates/incorporate.html',
                          RequestContext(request, form_params))
```

was the cause of the problem. I needed to replace that with:

```
retval = render_to_response('mainapp/templates/incorporate.html',
                                      RequestContext(request, form_params))
transaction.commit()
return retval
```

In addition, other SO answers reveal that the transaction management decorators **hide all exceptions** and instead raise the transaction management exception. Unfortunately, the easiest way to diagnose this is to run without the decorator, and see if an exception is occurring, or wrap your whole view in a try/except.

Answer (score 1):

Refs [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually)

> If your view changes data and doesn't commit() or rollback(), Django will raise a TransactionManagementError exception.

So you have change in transaction, and need a rollback or commit before the last return. `transaction.rollback_unless_managed()` will not work because transaction inside `commit_manually` is *managed*.

Comment: I forgot to mention that line 60 is inside a context processor (and hence outside of the `commit_manually` wrapped function). Will that make a difference?

Comment: also, switching that line to `commit()` doesn't help :(

Comment: This was actually key to me realising that the problem was as in my answer.

Comment: No its not. the context processor gets invoked when passing RequestContext instance to `render_to_response` method, which is still inside `@commit_manually`. Furthermore, you could check the `rollback_unless_managed` function in django/db/backends/__init__.py, which even set the state of the transaction to be 'has changes' and needs manual rollback or commit

Comment: Thanks - that explains why the change in my answer was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by decorating the context processor with `transaction.commit_on_success` eg

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def my_view(request):
    ...
    transaction.commit()
    return render_to_response("template.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request, my_ctx))


@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_context_processor(request):
    ...
```

Even db reads require a commit/rollback (including those inside a context processor) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#requirements-for-transaction-handling

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to my case.

Comment: If the context processor that's causing the problem is your own then you can just decorate it with `@transaction.commit_on_success` and revert your view to `return render_to_response(...`. By doing this it will be ok with *any* future view you create that uses manual transaction management (not just the one that you changed).

Comment: Right, but I don't see why you conclude that a context processor is the problem. I'm not saying it isn't, but no-one else has made that diagnosis yet.

Comment: Because clearly your view does commit/rollback the transaction (as does mine) yet there's still an error, and when I add the decorator the error is gone. Even db reads require a commit/rollback https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#requirements-for-transaction-handling
You yourself say 'Note that line 60 in the below is inside a context processor, and hence outside of the commit_manually-wrapped view.'

Comment: Right, but the problem went away when I fixed an exception being thrown inside the view. I have an answer about that.

Comment: The view is returning the result of `render_to_response` so everything done within it does is inside the view (including running the context processor).

Comment: Some context processors run before; some after. In any case, the fact of a context processor doesn't negate the fact that the solution was to fix an exception being thrown in the view.

Comment: In my case both your solution and my solution work, I prefer to use a decorator on the context processor as I don't want to implement the fix on each view that uses manual transaction handling.

Comment: Your solution would not work, because applying only that, there would still be an exception in the view.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works for me, maybe we don't have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't rolled my code back 26 days to test if your solution magically prevents exceptions.